# alternate method of Mootools addEvent in Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('test_div').addEvent('click', function() {
        formElement = $$('.field_search_criteria')[0]; // get it from <form class="field_search_criteria" id="field_search">

        // On search
        formElement.addEvent('submit', function(event) {
            event.stop();

        alert(formElement.toQueryString())
        });
    });
```

anybody can help me to convert the above mootools function to Jquery. What is the alternate Jquery of addEvent in Mootools

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you do know the original code leaks `formElement` into your global object, right? and also it's better written as `document.getElement('.field_searchCriteria')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  could use on()

```
//When i click on the element with id = test_div (substitue # with . if you are talking about a class)
$('#test_div').on('click', function() {
    //select the form with id = field_search
    formElement = $('#field_search'); // get it from <form class="field_search_criteria" id="field_search">

    // On Submit
    formElement.on('submit', function(event) {
        //prevent default action
        event.preventDefault();
        //alert  serialized data
        alert(formElement.serialize())
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
jQuery.fn.addEvent = jQuery.fn.bind;

//Usage
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('test_div').addEvent('submit',function(){ .... });
});
```

Comment: Yes, but he still has to change all the rest of the code to work in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

JQuery `on` function will do the trick.

```
$("#test_div").on("click", function() {});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/on/ for more info. To unbind the "click" event, use `off` like this:

```
 $("#test_div").off("click");
```

See http://api.jquery.com/off/ for more info.

Note: for earlier JQuery versions (<1.7), use `bind` and `unbind`. See http://api.jquery.com/bind/ and http://api.jquery.com/unbind/